# How, on a table, do I do a listobject.listColumns(1).find.row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table, with one of the columns is named ID.
I am trying to do a search of that column to find what row contains a certain value. I have tried many different commands, (all of which check our with the editor's syntax checking), but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.
My line of code that I am trying to make work is toward the bottom of the program and is foundrow = summObj.ListColumns("ID")...
Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Reload_Click()

    'Routine to move data to table from Molding Table
    'Check to not overwrite current records but add new ones.

    Dim summObj As ListObject
    Dim moldObj As ListObject
    Dim I, X As Integer
    Dim summObjRows As Integer
    Dim moldObjRows As Integer
    Dim key As String
    Dim foundrow As Integer

    ' Get the table reference
    Set summObj = Worksheets("Summary").ListObjects("SummaryTable")
    Set moldObj = Worksheets("MoldingData").ListObjects("MoldingTable")
    summObjRows = summObj.ListRows.Count
    moldObjRows = moldObj.ListRows.Count

    'Check if table is empty
    If summObjRows = 0 Then
        'Set up the first row
        summObj.ListRows.Add
        summObj.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange(1) = "New"
    End If

    X = 1
    For I = 1 To moldObj.ListRows.Count
        key = moldObj.DataBodyRange(I, moldObj.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.Column) & "," & moldObj.DataBodyRange(I, moldObj.ListColumns("6-Way").DataBodyRange.Column)
        If moldObj.DataBodyRange(I, moldObj.ListColumns("Volume").DataBodyRange.Column) <> "" Then

            If Not (key = summObj.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange(X)) Then
                'Insert row into Summary Table unless this is the first row in a blank table.
                If Not summObj.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange(X) = "New" Then
                    summObj.ListRows.Add (X)
                End If
                summObj.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange(X) = key
                summObj.ListColumns("Volume").DataBodyRange(X) = moldObj.ListColumns("Volume").DataBodyRange(I)
                summObj.ListColumns("Item Name").DataBodyRange(X) = moldObj.ListColumns("Item Name").DataBodyRange(I)
                summObj.ListColumns("Data1").DataBodyRange(X) = moldObj.ListColumns("Data1").DataBodyRange(I)
                summObj.ListColumns("Data2").DataBodyRange(X) = moldObj.ListColumns("Data2").DataBodyRange(I)
            Else
                summObj.ListColumns("Volume").DataBodyRange(X) = moldObj.ListColumns("Volume").DataBodyRange(I)
                summObj.ListColumns("Data2").DataBodyRange(X) = moldObj.ListColumns("Data2").DataBodyRange(I)
            End If
            X = X + 1
        Else
            'Check it to see if it is in Summary, and if so remove it
            foundrow = summObj.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange.Find(key).Row
        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

Thanks for helping me to solve this one.
Rich

I made a small change to the line in question.
I removed the (x) from the line.

Now what happens is that if the string is found in the column, then the row number is put in foundrow.  If the string is not in the column, then i get the runtime error '91'

Any additional thoughts?

Rich

Comment: Any particular reason for all these objects? https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the question.